# Open hundred of TCP (Websocket) Connections on one Client

Tags: linux, tcp, websocket, redhat, ulimit

I want to figure out how many connections my Server can handle. Thats why I wrote a script which actually creates a lot of connections (websocket-connections).

This works find until 200 Connections then it stops! 
I am guessing it has something to do with limits of the system: Red Hat Linux

I tried to change the values of ulimit but it didn't work ->  after reboot they were gone

Also I changed the value of the max File Handler:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max 
900000
```

-> also gone after reboot

Can someone tell me in what kind of system limit I am running into and how I can change that permantly?!

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) 14904
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 14904
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Comment: It seems more likely that your browser can't open more than 200 web sockets. Linux runs a significant portion of the Internet, it won't have any problem juggling more than 200 open connections...

Comment: I dont think so, cause the browser is still trying to connect new clients but the server doesnt respond anymore

Comment: Also when I use a differen System (OSX) I can at least have 259 Connections

Comment: @user1354743 How do you know that the browser is actually trying to open connections and not just pretending to be?

Comment: Because I was able to send messages! But I put it in a file now and create the connections without browser..this works better until you crash into server limits!